# Use spread operator to copy array state and add all objects that match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to sort all objects that match the regex into an array.
This does not seem to work with the spread operator and useState, is there any way I can do that?
The result I am getting now is the samples thing only gives me the last object that matches it and nothing else. 
The desired effect I want is all the samples that match get pushed into the samples state.

```
  const [accessories, setAccessories] = useState([]);
  const [paints, setPaints] = useState([]);
  const [samples, setSamples] = useState([]);

  // Load order into state
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUser();
    getOrderById(match.params.orderId);
  }, []);

  // Load order into state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      console.log(order.line_items);
      for (let i = 0; i < order.line_items.length; i++) {
        if (order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^(TAC|T.BU.AC)/)) {
          console.log('SKU: ', order.line_items[i].sku);
          //@ts-ignore
          setAccessories([...accessories, order.line_items[i]]);
          console.log(accessories);
        }
        if (order.line_items[i].sku.startsWith('TBA') || order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^TCR(?!0000)/)
          || order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^TCR0000/)) {
          //@ts-ignore
          setPaints([...paints, order.line_items[i]]);
        }
        if (order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^TCR\d+P?\d+SAMP/)) {
          console.log(samples);
          console.log(order.line_items[i]);
          //@ts-ignore
          setSamples([...samples, ...[order.line_items[i]]]);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [loading]);
```

Comment: `order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^TCR(?!0000)/) || order.line_items[i].sku.match(/^TCR0000/)` does not make sense - if the `sku` starts with TCR, at least one of those will evaluate to `true`. What's the logic you're looking for relating to 0000 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are few mistakes you're doing here.

#### Mistake 1:

Calling the same `setStates` way too many times inside a single `useEffect` block using a `for` loop, this might greatly affect React's performance. Again, this is clearly a violation of **[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)**, *Only Call Hooks at the Top Level*

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

#### Mistake 2:

Though this is not as serious as the previous ones, it's still a mistake. Not using better solutions, Use inbuilt JavaScript methods like `filter` instead of writing your own `for` loop

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let _accessories;
  let _paints;
  let _samples;

  if (!loading) {
    _accessories = order.line_items.filter(({ sku }) => sku.match(/^(TAC|T.BU.AC)/))

    _paints = order.line_items.filter(({ sku }) => sku.startsWith('TBA') || sku.match(/^TCR(?!0000)|^TCR0000/))

    _samples = order.line_items.filter(({ sku }) => sku.match(/^TCR\d+P?\d+SAMP/))

    // Never use setState inside a for loop
  // of useEffects
  // Also avoid calling same setState multiple times

  // use callback setState if you want to access
  // previous state, but it ain't a compulsory like
  // for class components
  setAccessories(s => [ ...s, ..._accessories ])
  setPaints(s => [ ...s, ..._paints ])  
  setSamples(s => [ ...s, ..._samples ])
  } 

  // return in useEffect has different role
  // than normal functions

}, [loading])
```

Answer (score 0):

Spread the results of calling `.filter` into the calls:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loading) {
    return;
  }
  const items = order.line_items;
  setAccessories([
    ...accessories,
    items.filter(({ sku }) => sku.match(/^(TAC|T.BU.AC)/))
  ]);
  setPaints([
    ...paints,
    items.filter(({ sku }) => sku.startsWith('TBA') || sku.match(/^TCR(?!0000)|^TCR0000/))
  ]);
  setSamples([
    ...samples,
    items.filter(item => item.sku.match(/^TCR\d+P?\d+SAMP/))
  ]);
}, [loading]);
```